# Unit test throws exception but cannot see the message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

Hi all I'm making a Chess AI as hobby project with Test Driven Development. But for some reason the only message my tests give is "test has thrown an exception: ...". And therefore omitting the only thing that matters. Instead of directly reading the error I now have to right-click and view test result details. I have tried adding and removing columns, but I cannot get the whole message to be shown directly.

Can VS2010 be setup so the exception message gets shown directly for each unit test?

edit: I am using standaard VS unit tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class MiniMaxTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConstructor()
    {
        throw new Exception("Must I click view details to see this?");
    }
}
```

Why these questions? You guys can reproduce these things. Debug or Run tests give the same messages:
[image: exception message remains hidden]

Comment: Could you provide more detail? For example, what testing framework are you using (MSTest)? What do your tests look like?

Comment: are you using MSTest? If not specify your unit test tool. Also why don't you just debug your test method?

Comment: If I got this right, you are saying that the field or column which shows the message is too short to display the entire exception? Well, unit tests are not supposed to constantly fail, so "clicking to see the details" once in a while shouldn't be such a big deal?

Comment: Attributes show this is MSTest

Comment: Please provide your source code here.

Comment: I'd say when doing TTD you start with all tests failing, improving step by step. Also I don't need any of the other details.

Comment: This is my source code, it don't matter what causes the exception, thats not my problem.

Comment: are you hitting the "Run Tests" button of "Debug tests" button?

Comment: Could you maybe post a screenshot detailing a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can configure VS to show it differently. The IDE shows the first line of the exception message, and there's a newline character in the full message text, so you'll need to click through to the details to view the whole thing.

What you *can* do however, is abuse the MSTest framework to show your own messages.

MS Test Assertions are all implemented by throwing exceptions. All the MS Test `Assert` functions throw exceptions which are derived from `UnitTestAssertException`. Visual studio has special handling for these kinds of exceptions.

For example: If you write this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AllAboard()
{
    throw new AssertFailedException("Failboat");
}
```

`AssertFailedException` is the standard base class for most other assertion failures.

You'll note that VS2010 does *not* print the generic "test threw an exception" message, instead it just prints "Failboat".

Now what you can do is surround your tests in things that convert normal exceptions into `AssertFailedException` and then you can print whatever messages you like.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStuff()
{
    try
    {
        string o = null; // pretend this came from some real code
        var x = o.Split(new[] { ',' }); // this will throw NullRefException
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new AssertFailedException(e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

Of course, I wouldn't recommend actually doing this... it's verbose, and more importantly, you lose the call stack... but hey, now you've got one more tool in your toolbelt

Comment: @Basic yeah, I totally wouldn't do this, but VS doesn't give you any options... so if you reaaaaaaaaaaaally want to change the messages, that's what you've gotta do :-)